# fastest way to re-encode x264 videos using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello I am looking for the fastest way to fastest way to re-encode x264 mp4 and insert keyframes while using minimal resource as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-preset ultrafast`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts vid.m3u8
```

- It is recommended to use the slowest `-preset` you can. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.
- You can also add `-codec:a copy` to stream copy the audio to avoid re-encoding it.
- If you have access to a [hardware accelerated H.264 encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) then you can look into using that instead, but none are as efficient as x264 (quality per bit).

> fastest way to re-encode [...] while using minimal resource as possible

This is mutually exclusive. Video encoding is resource intensive you have to make a compromise between encoding speed, efficiency, and less resource use. If you want to use fewer resources the result is slower encoding and/or lower quality per bit.

Comment: Is there a good source to read on this? Do resources required for encoding also depend on the file size of the input source?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of x264 (ffmpeg) settings that speed up things whilst keeping good quality and modest file size with crf one pass encoding: veryfast (wouldn't go above), me=hex, subme=5, crf=23, size=640x360, aspect 16:9, key frame interval aka gop 250, audio aac 96-128 kbps & 44.1 kHz.

There are many other settings, but these are speedwise the most important I think.

Conversion time becomes important when you want to convert entire films.
For shorter videos, let's say up to 1/2 hours, a lower crf (18 to 22), a lower (more editable) gop and a subme above 7 is a possible choice.
I recently noticed a significant difference in conversion time between crf 22 and the default of 23 (with ffmpeg). This on a dual core pc with 8 Gb ram (same result with 4 Gb ram).
In case of crf 22 the conversion fps stays around 75. In case of 23 it mounts to 110 to 115. The speed level with crf 22 is between 2.9x and 3.5x. With crf 23 between 3.5x and 5x, mostly around 4.0 to 4.5.

With the veryfast, crf 23, s 640x360, me=hex and subme=5, gop 250, aac 128/44.1 stereo setting converting the video and audio of a 2:38:30 movie took 34 minutes. In case of crf 22 it takes 45 minutes...

The original movie had a 1280x528 px resolution. The aac was 48 kHz. The gop (reduces file size a lot!) already was the default 250. It was 2 pass encoded with an overall bitrate of 878 kbps.
The file size was 995 Mb, the file size has become 325 Mb.

After the conversion the quality is still very good.

As long as the results of AVC/x264 are so decent, I'm not thinking of starting to use HEVC or AV1 or libvpx etc, as those take double or triple the time to convert. Hardly taking into account that not everyone can buy a new super machine to convert videos. In the Third World e.g.